# Select/Option/Value on change using Classic ASP

Tags: javascript, vbscript, asp-classic

I tried to create a select option value on change using classic ASP but it didn't work. No error but when I view, nothing pop up from second select.

I like to select student name from first select box, if it matches, then second box shows course name, and third box shows Semester.

I like to store student names and StudentID into DB.

Can anyone help?

Students table

```
StudentID   Firstname   Lastname
-------------------------------
01         AAA         LN1
02         BBB         LN2
03         CCC         LN3
```

Class table

```
Course    CourseID StudentID Semester
-------------------------------------
History   C01      01        Spring
History   C01      01        Summer
Math      C02      02        Spring
Math      C02      02        Fall
```

Code

```
            <%          Set oRs = Server.CreateObject("adodb.recordset")
                            strSQL = " SELECT StudentID, Firstname, Lastname FROM Students Where StudentID = '" & Request.ServerVariables("LOGON_Student") & "'"
                            oRs.Open strSQL, myConn
                            sName = oRs("Lastname") & ", " & oRs("Firstname")
                            if not oRs.eof then %>
                                            <select name="Students" id="selectStudent" onChange="this.form.action='default.asp';this.form.submit();">
            <option value="<%= oRs(0) %>" <% if trim(request.Form("Students")) = trim(oRs(0)) then response.write " selected "end if %>><%= sName %></option>
            <option value="<%= oRs("StudentID") %>" hidden></option>
                                            </select>
                            <%          end if
            %>
             <%          if request.Form("Students") <> "" then
                            strSQL = " SELECT Course FROM Class WHERE StudentID = '" & request.Form("StudentID") & "'"
                            Set oRs = Server.CreateObject("adodb.RecordSet")
                            oRs.Open strSQL, myConn
                            if not oRs.eof then %>
                                            <select name="Class" id="selectClass" onChange="this.form.action='default.asp';this.form.submit();">
                                                            <% do until oRs.eof  %>
                                                                            <option value="<%= oRs(0) %>" <% if trim(request.Form("Class")) = trim(oRs(0)) then response.write " selected "end if %>><%= oRs(0) %></option>
                                                            <% oRs.MoveNext
                                                                            loop       %>
                                            </select>
                            <% end if
                            end if
            %>
            <%          if request.Form("Class") <> "" then
                            strSQL = " SELECT Semester FROM Class WHERE Course = '" & request.Form("Course") & "'"
                            Set oRs = Server.CreateObject("adodb.RecordSet")
                            oRs.Open strSQL, myConn
                            if not oRs.eof then %>
                                            <select name="Class" id="selectClass" onChange="this.form.action='default.asp';this.form.submit();">
                                                            <% do until oRs.eof  %>
                                                                            <option value="<%= oRs(0) %>" <% if trim(request.Form("Class")) = trim(oRs(0)) then response.write " selected "end if %>><%= oRs(0) %></option>
                                                            <% oRs.MoveNext
                                                                            loop       %>
                                            </select>
                            <% end if
                            end if
            %>
```

Comment: "Subselect" is not a standard HTML term so it's hard to figure out what you mean. Could you please edit the question and provide a sample of the expected HTML?

Comment: I changed the title. Thanks.

Comment: Do you want to manipulate the DOM in the browser from a server-side script?

Comment: I don't manipulate DOM. I like to make it simple as what I did. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using wrong value in your SQL statement.

You should use the name of the first drop down element, not the name of the database field.

Also, you really better use parameters, not inject the value directly, as this can let the user take control of your database and possibly whole server. (To learn more, read about SQL Injection attacks.)

So, correct SQL would be:

```
strSQL = "SELECT Course FROM Class WHERE StudentID = ?"
Set oCommand = Server.Createobject("ADODB.Command")
Set oCommand.ActiveConnection = myConn
oCommand.CommandText = strSQL
oCommand.Parameters.Append(oCommand.CreateParameter("StudentID", 3, , , Request.Form("Students")) )
Set oRS = oCommand.Execute
```

Make sure to remove the line `oRs.Open strSQL, myConn` from your code when having this.

As you see, I changed `Request.Form("StudentID")` to `Request.Form("Students")`, and now the query should return results.